# How can I call with_items task registered output in another with_items task?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I'm trying to create a playbook that will lookup the AWS ARN for an SSL certificate for each of our clients and then use the results with a template to update a custom dictionary.

```yaml
  tasks:
  - name: Find ARN
    shell: aws acm list-certificates --output text --certificate-statuses ISSUED | grep {{ apache[item].domain }} | awk '{print $2}'
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
    with_items:
    - "clientA"
    - "clientB"
    - "clientC"
    register: sslarn
  - debug: msg={{ item.stdout_lines }}
    with_items:
    - "{{ sslarn.results }}"
  - name: Remake the dictionary assemble files
    template:
      src: /file/path/to/templates/update-dictionary-template.j2
      dest: /file/path/to/dictionary/files/{{ item }}.yml
      mode: 0644
    with_items:
    - "clientA"
    - "clientB"
    - "clientC"
  - name: Assemble the dictionary
    assemble:
      ignore_hidden: yes
      src: /file/path/to/dictionary/files/
      dest: /file/path/to/dictionary/dictionary.yml
```

I'm able to find the ARN without any issues in the first task. However, when I try to use debug to figure out how to call the ARN per client for the template task I'm unable to figure out how to only get the ARN for the specific client out of the registered results.

Comment: Read about [using `register` in a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop). You will need to loop over `sslarn.results` in subsequent tasks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make it a [mre]. We can only guess what your register looks like, what is the result you get when debugging `sslarn.results`, what is your template, the result you get from it and the one you expect instead. Hence it is not possible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever module is used in an iteration the items of the list *results* always comprise the attribute *item*. Use the handy pattern `dict(keys|zip(values))` and create a dictionary where the *keys* is the list of the attribute *items* and *values* is the list *results*. If you register the variable *sslarn* declare the dictionary

```yaml
  sslarn_dict: "{{ dict(sslarn.results|map(attribute='item')|
                        zip(sslarn.results)) }}"
```

For example, given the clients

```yaml
  clients: [clientA, clientB, clientC]
```

, running on the localhost only, the below iteration

```yaml
    - command: "echo certificate-statuses {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ clients }}"
      register: sslarn
```

gives

```yaml
  sslarn_dict:
    clientA:
      ansible_facts: {discovered_interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python3}
      ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: true
      cmd: [echo, certificate-statuses, clientA]
      delta: '0:00:00.003085'
      end: '2023-07-11 06:55:46.144448'
      failed: false
      invocation:
        module_args: {_raw_params: echo certificate-statuses clientA, _uses_shell: false,
          argv: null, chdir: null, creates: null, executable: null, removes: null, stdin: null,
          stdin_add_newline: true, strip_empty_ends: true}
      item: clientA
      msg: ''
      rc: 0
      start: '2023-07-11 06:55:46.141363'
      stderr: ''
      stderr_lines: []
      stdout: certificate-statuses clientA
      stdout_lines: [certificate-statuses clientA]
    clientB:
      ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: true
      cmd: [echo, certificate-statuses, clientB]
      delta: '0:00:00.003012'
      end: '2023-07-11 06:55:46.367788'
      failed: false
      invocation:
        module_args: {_raw_params: echo certificate-statuses clientB, _uses_shell: false,
          argv: null, chdir: null, creates: null, executable: null, removes: null, stdin: null,
          stdin_add_newline: true, strip_empty_ends: true}
      item: clientB
      msg: ''
      rc: 0
      start: '2023-07-11 06:55:46.364776'
      stderr: ''
      stderr_lines: []
      stdout: certificate-statuses clientB
      stdout_lines: [certificate-statuses clientB]
    clientC:
      ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: true
      cmd: [echo, certificate-statuses, clientC]
      delta: '0:00:00.003018'
      end: '2023-07-11 06:55:46.584018'
      failed: false
      invocation:
        module_args: {_raw_params: echo certificate-statuses clientC, _uses_shell: false,
          argv: null, chdir: null, creates: null, executable: null, removes: null, stdin: null,
          stdin_add_newline: true, strip_empty_ends: true}
      item: clientC
      msg: ''
      rc: 0
      start: '2023-07-11 06:55:46.581000'
      stderr: ''
      stderr_lines: []
      stdout: certificate-statuses clientC
      stdout_lines: [certificate-statuses clientC]
```

---

Now, you can use the dictionary in a template. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat update-dictionary-template.j2
{{ item }}: {{ sslarn_dict[item]['stdout'] }}
```

```yaml
    - template:
        src: update-dictionary-template.j2
        dest: /tmp/files/{{ item }}.yml
      loop: "{{ clients }}"
```

will create files

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/files/
/tmp/files/
├── clientA.yml
├── clientB.yml
└── clientC.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/files/clientA.yml 
clientA: certificate-statuses clientA
```

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/files/clientB.yml 
clientB: certificate-statuses clientB
```

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/files/clientC.yml 
clientC: certificate-statuses clientC
```

You can assemble the file */tmp/dictionary.yml*

```yaml
    - assemble:
        src: /tmp/files
        dest: /tmp/dictionary.yml
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/dictionary.yml 
clientA: certificate-statuses clientA
clientB: certificate-statuses clientB
clientC: certificate-statuses clientC
```

However, you can get the same content without assembling the intermediate files. The template below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for client in clients %}
          {{ client }}: {{ sslarn_dict[client]['stdout'] }}
          {% endfor %}
```

But, the easiest way is to create a dictionary from selected attributes only

```yaml
  client_stdout: "{{ sslarn.results|
                     items2dict(key_name='item', value_name='stdout') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  client_stdout:
    clientA: certificate-statuses clientA
    clientB: certificate-statuses clientB
    clientC: certificate-statuses clientC
```

Then, the template is trivial

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ client_stdout }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    clientA: certificate-statuses clientA
    clientB: certificate-statuses clientB
    clientC: certificate-statuses clientC
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    clients: [clientA, clientB, clientC]
    sslarn_dict: "{{ dict(sslarn.results|map(attribute='item')|
                          zip(sslarn.results)) }}"
    client_stdout: "{{ sslarn.results|
                       items2dict(key_name='item', value_name='stdout') }}"

  tasks:

    - command: "echo certificate-statuses {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ clients }}"
      register: sslarn
    - debug:
        var: sslarn_dict|to_yaml

    - template:
        src: update-dictionary-template.j2
        dest: /tmp/files/{{ item }}.yml
      loop: "{{ clients }}"

    - assemble:
        src: /tmp/files
        dest: /tmp/dictionary.yml

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for client in clients %}
          {{ client }}: {{ sslarn_dict[client]['stdout'] }}
          {% endfor %}

    - debug:
        var: client_stdout

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ client_stdout }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Defining the results as a var the way you showed with `sslarn_dict` did exactly what I wanted it to do. I got an error with the items2dict variation, but that's because I'm on ansible 2.6 and it was added in ansible 2.7. I'm sure it would work for others.

Comment: You must be joking. Ansible 2.6 EOL was in 2019. See [supported versions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#releases-and-maintenance).